How can I dynamically add select items in a LINQ query?
I have this:
IQueryable<ScreenerData> query = _context.ScreenerData;

which is financial metrics I have made a screener which filters out items. But I want to return some fixed data which doesn't change + the conditions based on my input so for example the fixed data might be something like revenue, pe, ebit but in the filter I have something like marketcap > 1000 and so I want to pass back revenue, pe, ebit, marketcap
query = query
     .Where(i => i.security_type == "stock")
     .Where(i => i.screener_last_updated != null)
     .Where(i => i.screener_last_updated >= tenDaysAgo)
     .Where(i => siQIds.Contains(i.id))
     .OrderByDescending(sortLambda);

I am currently doing the above and then using reflection to get all the items:
var properties = typeof(ScreenerData).GetProperties();
var selectedData = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

foreach (var item in query)
{
    var data = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (conditions.Any(c => c.variable == property.Name))
        {
            data[property.Name] = property.GetValue(item);
        }
    }

    data["id"] = item.id;
    data["revenue"] = item.revenue;
    data["pe"] = item.pe;
    data["ebit"] = item.ebit;
}

This works fine except that its essentially doing select * from table where as I want it to select id, revenue, pe, ebit, marketcap from table.
I would really appreciate some help on this as I have tried some different examples on stack overflow and couldn't get them to work.

Are you using Entity Framework? Add tag. Specify the exact version.

yes EntityFrameworkCore I added it

Look at Dynamic LINQ library. In it, you can set the desired properties as a string: .Select("new(Property1, Property2)").

i.screener_last_updated != null serves no purspose, the next filter eliminates nulls. SQL allows you to compare things to NULL without throwing. All comparisons with NULL return NULL and are treated as failures though. That means i.screener_last_updated >= tenDaysAgo eliminates nulls
